# Is there any way to run Steam on one screen, while having access to my desktop on the other?

Tags: ubuntu, steam

Not much more to add really.

All of the games I play on Steam only use one screen, is there any way to have my desktop active on the second screen or is this not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you need "Actual Multiple Monitors"

and here is the video of how to configure it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqqZlAlM0AI

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using desktop virtualization software like SoftXpand

See video ~ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6IarpedJ60

That's the only realistic way I can see it working without Steam minimizing whilst you are using the keyboard/mouse on the second monitor.